# Merge build files into single one file in Angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

After the migration of Angular 17 to vite, I encountered a problem that it was not possible to merge all new files into one single file without changing the builder to the old one @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser

Build occurs through a command
`ng build --output-hashing=none --configuration=production && node build.js`

At the same time, the code in build.js is as simple as possible:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const concat = require("concat");

const componentPath = "./dist/build/bundle.js";

(async function build() {
    const files = [
        "./dist/angular-app/runtime.js",
        "./dist/angular-app/main.js",
        "./dist/angular-app/polyfills.js"
    ].filter(x => fs.pathExistsSync(x));
    await fs.ensureFile(componentPath);
    await concat(files, componentPath);
})();
```

This code works fine when using the old builder, but with the new angular:application this approach does not work - an error is thrown

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Why would you even do that ? I would break lazy loading !

Comment: Using this method, different applications are built into a common portal

Comment: My current application does not have lazy loading, so nothing will break; in other applications with lazy loading, i do not build all files (chunks) into one single file, but only main.js and pollyfill.js

Comment: But do you need that? There are no advantages to do that.

Comment: I want to include different Angular micro apps into one page, but I don’t want to connect a bunch of polyfills, it’s better to merge it all in one file and add it via <script /> tag

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Angular 17:
add vite and rewrite build.js to:

```
import "./dist/angular-app/browser/polyfills";
import "./dist/angular-app/browser/main";
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: "[name].js"
            },
            input: "build.js"
        },
        outDir: "./dist/build"
    }
});
```

then you can run: `ng build --output-hashing=none --configuration=production && vite build`

Comment: Does it contain styles.css also? You anyway we should bring it separately?

Comment: After executing the script, you will have a separate dist directory, where styles.css will be located